# Problem with number output to DOS console in NASM Assembler

Tags: assembly, nasm, x86-16

We have the following task: write a program that sets the default values of x and y (in the program these are 3 and 5 respectively), then it compares these numbers and replaces the lesser of them with the half-sum of x and y, and replaces the greater of them with twice the multiplication of x and y.

```
section .data
x dw 3
y dw 5

section .text
global _start

_start:
  ; Сравним значения x и y
  mov ax, [x]
  cmp ax, [y]
  
  ; Если x <= y, переходим к метке less_than
  jle less_than
  
  ; Если x > y, переходим к метке greater_than
  jmp greater_than

less_than:
  ; Найдем полусумму x и y и заменим меньшее значение на нее
  mov bx, [x]
  add bx, [y]
  shr bx, 1
  mov [x], bx
  
  ; Умножим большее значение на 2
  mov bx, [y]
  shl bx, 1
  mov [y], bx
  
  ; Выведем значения x и y
  mov ah, 02h ; функция вывода символа на экран
  mov dl, byte [x] ; выводим x
  add dl, '0' ; преобразуем в символ
  int 21h ; вызов BIOS
  
  mov ah, 02h ; функция вывода символа на экран
  mov dl, byte [y] ; выводим y
  add dl, '0' ; преобразуем в символ
  int 21h ; вызов BIOS
  
  ; Завершаем программу
  mov ah, 4Ch
  xor al, al
  int 21h
  
greater_than:
  ; Найдем полусумму x и y и заменим меньшее значение на нее
  mov bx, [x]
  add bx, [y]
  shr bx, 1
  mov [y], bx
  
  ; Умножим большее значение на 2
  mov bx, [x]
  shl bx, 1
  mov [x], bx
  
  ; Выведем значения x и y
  mov ah, 02h ; функция вывода символа на экран
  mov dl, byte [x] ; выводим x
  add dl, '0' ; преобразуем в символ
  int 21h ; вызов BIOS
  
  mov ah, 02h ; функция вывода символа на экран
  mov dl, byte [y] ; выводим y
  add dl, '0' ; преобразуем в символ
  int 21h ; вызов BIOS
  
  ; Завершаем программу
  mov ah, 4Ch
  xor al, al
  int 21h
```

When I compile my program, I get just "Pp" when I should get 4 and 30 respectively.
[image: screenshot of just the Pp]

Comment: You seem to use SMALL memory model but you didn't initialize `DS` to section `.data`.
*multiplication of x and y* is missing. Your simplified method of conversion binary  to decimal digit works only for numbers below 10.

Answer (score 1):

One of your results (4 and 30) has more than 1 digit. You need a better way of outputting the multi-digit numbers. See [Displaying numbers with DOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45904075/displaying-numbers-with-dos).

---

> then it compares these numbers and replaces the lesser of them with the **half-sum of x and y**, and replaces the greater of them with **twice the multiplication of x and y**

- It would be best to not start by comparing the numbers and then have to duplicate a lot of code. First calculate the replacement expressions and keep the results in registers. (eg. `mov [x], bx` would destroy x before you could use it next)

  ```
    mov bx, [x]
    add bx, [y]
    shr bx, 1      ; -> BX is "half-sum of x and y"

    mov ax, [x]
    mul word [y]
    shl ax, 1      ; -> AX is "twice the multiplication of x and y"
  ```
- Then compare the numbers and load x and y accordingly:

  ```
      mov  cx, [x]
      cmp  cx, [y]
      jl   less_than
      xchg ax, bx    ; Just swapping the new values
    less_than:
      mov  [x], bx
      mov  [y], ax
  ```

> replaces the **lesser** of them

The `jle less_than` instruction is branching on Less**OrEqual**. Following the task description that really should become `jl less_than`.